# R plotly highlight_key function only highlights half of the bar

Tags: r, plotly

When I use `plotly` in R to plot a bar chart which has highlighting function by clicking, only half of the bar is highlighted, as can be reproduced by the following script.

```
library(plotly)

D = data.frame(
  NAME = LETTERS[1:5],
  VALUE = rnorm(5)
)

D %>% 
  highlight_key(~NAME) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~VALUE, y = ~NAME, type ="bar", orientation = "h") %>% 
  highlight(on = "plotly_click",off = "plotly_doubleclick")
```

What I can see in my Rstudio:

[image]

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this issue?

Comment: I believe someone already posted an answer and I have approved it. Strange it disappeared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue by added `layout(barmode = "overlay")`.

```
library(plotly)

D = data.frame(
  NAME = LETTERS[1:5],
  VALUE = rnorm(5)
)

D %>% 
  highlight_key(~NAME) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~VALUE, y = ~NAME, type ="bar", orientation = "h") %>% 
  highlight(on = "plotly_click",off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>%
  layout(barmode = "overlay")
```

[image]

Alternatively it is possible to use `selectedpoints` in `plot_ly` function.