# Plotly R Highlight Problem: When I Click on a Bar, the Hightlighting Looks Wrong

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to add a feature to my plot where someone can click on a bar and highlight it. When I try to add this feature, however, I am only able to click on the bar and highlight a fraction of it (see images below). I tried implementing the advice in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162823/r-plotly-highlight-key-function-only-highlights-half-of-the-bar), but to no avail. Insight would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
number_of_debates_from_1803_1910 <- fread("~/projects/hansard-shiny/app-data/introduction/number_of_debates_from_1803_1910.csv")
  
  number_of_debates_from_1803_1910 %>%
    highlight_key() %>%
    plot_ly(
          x = ~decade, 
          y = ~no_of_debates, 
          type = 'bar', 
          text = ~paste0("Decade: ", "<b>", decade, "</b>", "\n",
                         "Number of Debates: ", "<b>", no_of_debates, "</b>", "\n"),
          hoverinfo = "text",
          marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                        line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                                    width = 1.5))) %>% 
    highlight(on = "plotly_click", off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>%
    layout(barmode = "overlay"),
           xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title = "")) %>%
    config(displayModeBar = F)
```

This is my data:

```
decade,no_of_debates
1800,926
1810,2435
1820,2400
1830,7848
1840,7398
1850,8835
1860,10660
1870,14051
1880,31509
1890,31857
1900,49725
1910,5631
```

Which, if you prefer, can also be accessed as:

```
structure(list(decade = c(1800L, 1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L,  1850L), no_of_debates = c(926L, 2435L, 2400L, 7848L, 7398L, 8835L )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ))
```

Picture of a plot before clicking on a bar:
[image]

Picture of a plot after clicking on a bar:
[image]

Comment: Please share your data by posting the output of `dput(head(number_of_debates_from_1803_1910))`.

Comment: This is the output you want to look at? 

`structure(list(decade = c(1800L, 1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 
1850L), no_of_debates = c(926L, 2435L, 2400L, 7848L, 7398L, 8835L
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5632c3fc2450>)`

Comment: Exactly - this makes it easier for others to copy your data. For data.table you'll need to remove the `.internal.selfref`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of removing `.internal.selfref`. I tried loading the csv as a data frame instead, to avoid problems that might be associated with data.table, but my plot has the same issue when I click it.

Comment: But thank you for the copying data tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close to the solution to your question. For whatever reason, `class` is important for the data that you're highlighting. So for example, in your data, the class of `decade` is `int`, however, what it needs to be is `factor`. Fixing this is an easy solution

```
number_of_debates_from_1803_1910$decade <- as.factor(number_of_debates_from_1803_1910$decade)

number_of_debates_from_1803_1910 %>%
  highlight_key(~decade) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~decade, 
    y = ~no_of_debates, 
    type = 'bar', 
    text = ~paste0("Decade: ", "<b>", decade, "</b>", "\n",
                   "Number of Debates: ", "<b>", no_of_debates, "</b>", "\n"),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                  line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                              width = 1.5))) %>% 
  highlight(~decade, on = "plotly_click",off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>%
  layout(barmode = "overlay")
```

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize data type was so important here!