# Plotly highlight problem in R Shiny: Nothing is highlighted

Tags: r, plotly, highlight

I am trying to add a feature in my Shiny app where a user can click a point on a scatterplot and it will be highlighted. This seems simple enough, but in my example below, I can't seem to get anything to be highlighted at all, no matter how many variations I try. I've looked through the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122460/plotly-r-highlight-problem-when-i-click-on-a-bar-the-hightlighting-looks-wrong) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162823/r-plotly-highlight-key-function-only-highlights-half-of-the-bar), but they don't seem to help.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    
    column(6,
           h3("Scatterplot"),
           plotlyOutput("phylo_tree")),
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
  # Phylogenetic Tree
  output$phylo_tree <- renderPlotly({

    
    # Create a scatter plot using plot_ly
    scatter_plot <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
                            color = ~cyl, size = ~hp, text = ~paste("Car: ", rownames(mtcars)))%>%
      # Highlight selected point 
      highlight(~mpg, on = "plotly_click",off = "plotly_doubleclick")
    
    
    
    scatter_plot
  })

}


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried including many variations of the arguments documented [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.10.3/topics/highlight), but I consistently get the same result: In the R Shiny app, nothing is highlighted when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with the `shiny` framework, but with the `plotly` code itself. Changing it to

```
scatter_plot <- mtcars |> highlight_key(~mpg) |>
      plot_ly(x = ~mpg,y = ~wt,type = "scatter",mode = "markers",color = ~cyl,
              size = ~hp,text = paste("Car: ",rownames(mtcars))) |>
      highlight(on = "plotly_click",off = "plotly_doubleclick")
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. For anyone else curious, this code highlights all points that are at the same level of mpg. In order to highlight one point only, one would replace ~mpg with a unique point identifier.